# fsanitize with gcc causing unexpected early exit

Tags: c++, gcc, clang++

I've got an error *that isn't consistently reproducible* where `free()` is called on an invalid heap pointer.  Reducing this problem to "minimal" is fundamentally not possible with the code in question--(once I've done that, it's solved).  I'm unable to spot any obvious problems (such as a potential case where `calloc` is never called, or a double free, etc...)

I believe `valgrind` would be a solve for this except that the performance impact will be too extreme (these are client->server calls with timeouts, and operations that are expensive to begin with...>4 seconds in some cases)

This leaves me with `fsanitize=address`, I believe?  My experience so far with this has been...not great.

What I've got is two static libs and an executable that links with them.  I've turned on `fsanitize=address` for all three of them.  With `-fsanitize=address`, the code exits cleanly under the debugger during a *very* thoroughly tested and correct init routine (in the middle of a 256 byte `memcpy` into a 16 meg heap allocation--exit code 1).

Can anyone with practical experience using `fsanitize` provide me any tips on where the problem may lie?  I'm using gcc/ld under cmake and the code is (fundamentally) C compiled with C++.  Switching to clang is probably an option if that might improve things.

Typical compile command for a file:

```
"command": "/usr/bin/c++   -I. -I/home/redacted -fpermissive -g -g3 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fsanitize=address   
-std=gnu++11 -o core/CMakeFiles/nginx_core.dir/src/core/nginx.cpp.o -c /home/redacted.cpp",
```

Comment: Is the gcc  MALLOC_CHECK_ an option? It is good at catching double/wild free's

Comment: Also sanitize has a bunch of options.  Maybe you can twiddle the options to get around the spurious error, https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerFlags#run-time-flags

Comment: Thanks for the tip on MALLOC_CHECK.  Just added, although I should note that the initial problem happens about once every 24 hours under heavy load, which is why I'm interested in a fairly heavy duty tool that's less likely to miss a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just going to leave this here for future searchers having problems with `fsanitize`.  tldr;--*It worked*.  I had two fundamental problems:

1. fsanitize was outputting thorough error information about the reason it was exiting.  This was getting swallowed by `nginx`...and in our customized version of it getting redirected to an obscure log file.  Not sure why under `gdb` I wasn't getting a debug break, but nevertheless...it was detecting a legit error.  Key piece of info here:  Setting a breakpoint in `__asan_report_error` will halt the program before exit so you can inspect your various frames.
2. While the initialization routine is correct and heavily tested, as I mentioned, it does require its client to correctly allocate a (non-trivial) configuration structure.  In this case, the structure was 1 byte short of complete, causing a 1 byte overread.